# Reading images stored in internal storage from another app

Tags: android

I have a simple question.

It's possible to access to `DCIM` folder (internal storage) from an `app` and retrieve an `image`?

I've found solutions that use something like `Enviroment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` but I don't understand why.

Comment: `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStrorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");
File files[] = dir.listFiles();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/DCIM/Camera";
```

or

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()
```

Will give you a **path** for the public **directory**. This path is required to fetch all files including image. `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is public so you can access them from any installed app.

The following code snippet can be used to list all image file path from "DCIM" folder:

```
public static List<String> getCameraImages(Context context) {
    public final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/DCIM/Camera";
    public final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID = String.valueOf(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase().hashCode());

    final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = { CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
        projection, 
        selection, 
        selectionArgs, 
        null);

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = 
cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            result.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```